# TikTok api как использовать?

Tags: php, node.js, взлом

К тиктоку есть пару неофициальных api (вот например самый многофункциональный https://github.com/szdc/tiktok-api).

Проблема в том что для работы он требует использовать `device_id, fp, iid, openudid`, эти данные нужно получать перехватом трафика `man-in-the-middle proxy`, задача состоит в том чтобы сделать `REST API` для мобильного приложения, т.е. чтобы вся работа по поиску данных происходила на сервере.

Как сделать это на телефоне в принципе понятно, например приложение `Packet Capture` создает VPN соединение и каким-то образом перехватывает траффик из приложения ТикТока, при этом там еще нужно расшифровывать https ssl.

А каким образом это можно сделать на сервере, кто-нибудь работал с подобным?

Comment: удалось разобраться?

Comment: нашел вот такое вот, думаю поможет https://thumbs.gfycat.com/AltruisticUncommonHarborporpoise-size_restricted.gif